# Unable to type the section char in Minecraft 1.14.3

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

Whenever I try using Alt+2+1 to get the section char (§) in Minecraft, I get ☻.

I also am unable to paste the section char.

I use a Corsair K55 RGB Keyboard and am running Windows 10.\

If you need more information, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an 'alt gr' key on your keyboard? If yes, try to use this instead of 'alt'.
Else it may be that your keyboard-layout is wrong set.
Try to change the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft specifically does not allow you to use the section character at all in-game. The ampersand symbol `&` is commonly used as a replacement, but must be explicitly supported where you use it.